# Which RegEx expression to find in notepad++?

Tags: regex

I have in Notepad++ plenty of datetime texts like:

```
'20160310 17:59:00'
```

And I want to add '-' character to separate numbers in the date like

```
'2016-03-10 17:59:00'
```

How I would be a RegEx expression to do that?

Comment: this is simple..what have you tried?

Comment: Actually, to find the text I used '\d{8}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}' but can't figure how to split the first \d{8} part to add '-' character between each 2 numbers ilke to have '2016-03-10...'

Comment: you should make a group as `(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})` and replace it as `$1-$2-$3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex expression:

```
('\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

Combined with the following replace expression:

```
$1-$2-$3
```

will achieve what you want.

Explanation:

- `('\d{4})` capture group 1: an apostrophe followed by 4 digits
- `(\d{2})` capture group 2: 2 digits
- `(\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')` capture group 3: 2 digits, a space, 2 digits, a colon, 2 digits, a colon and 2 digits, followed by an apostrophe

`$1-$2-$3` - capture group 1, followed by a `-`, followed by capture group 2, followed by a `-`, followed by capture group 3

Comment: Thanks keith... after a little test with your suggest I found better put first ' inside first (\d{4}) like ('\d{4}) so I could be sure to match what exactly I am searching for! :-)